# Is there any constant time spatial indexing of points on the surface of a sphere with balanced partitioning?

Tags: math, indexing, geometry, geospatial

A simple way to index points in a Sphere is to use polar coordinates. That is, to find the index of a point, you convert it to polar coordinates and apply the formula `polar_ang * width + azimuthal_ang`. The problem with that strategy is that it isn't evenly spaced - indices near the center of the sphere have bigger areas than those near the top.

[image]

Is there any alternative indexing strategy that is equally as simple but with better partitioning properties?

Comment: You might want to look up fibonacci grids on a sphere.

Comment: You can equalize point density with Cos(polar_angle) multiplier

Answer (score 1):

Use a subdivided icosahedron. There are 12 vertices and 20 triangular faces. Each of these faces can be subdivided into grids of smaller triangles to arbitrarily small size. Not all the subdivided triangles have equal area, but the range of possible areas is fairly well bounded.